# CUDA: Can I safely assume compiler stops after false in an && expression

Tags: cuda, boolean-expression

Question: Can I safely assume the CUDA compiler stops the evaluation after the first `false` in an `&&` expression?

```
if ( condition1 && foo() )
{
    // do something
}
```

if `condition1` is `false` then `foo()` must **not** be called [would result in undefined behavior]

or should I better code it like this:

```
if ( condition1 )
{
    if ( foo() )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be best answered by disassembly of your compiled, optimised code.

Comment: I was thinking about this but how to get this code? This are not Intel instructions what I saw that far.

Comment: There is complete documentation for the PTX virtual assembly language in the CUDA documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `&&` evaluates operands starting from the left side. If leftmost operand is `false` it mustn't continue evaluation. If it's true, evaluation will continue to the right operand ans so on.

In your case, `foo()` won't be called when `condition1 == false`, as this is where evaluation will terminate. So I would go with the first code snippet.

Comment: This is what I know but the question if the CUDA compiler follows this rule.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would suspect nvcc behaves differently then (most) C/C++ compilers?

Comment: The CUDA C/C++ compiler [claims to be compliant](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support) with specific versions of C++: "The input source code is processed according to the C++ ISO/IEC 14882:2003 or C++ ISO/IEC 14882:2011 specifications".  Therefore, barring a specific documented exception for short-circuiting rules (I don't believe there is one), I would expect that any deviation in behavior between CUDA C++ and other C++ compliant compilers in this respect would be considered a bug or defect in the CUDA C++ compiler.

Comment: Yes Robert, I was awaiting your reply :-) and you did not disappoint me. I wrote already hours ago to Mark from Nvidia and I guess he will reply more or less the same. I am already using this feature heavily but I must assure it does not change and your answer confirms me it will remain as it is.